# Python pulling sp500 from yahoo api stalled at stock LMT

Tags: python, finance

So i am running my code which you can see below. This code pulls data from yahoo api and returns said data as CSV to my computer. But it gets through about half of it and it stops at LTM why is that and how can I fix it......also if anyone knows this answer much appreciated --> how would I UPDATE THESE CSV's each day any easy solution.

error-->  raise RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?ignore=.csv&e=31&g=d&s=LMT&b=1&a=0&c=2000&d=11&f=2016 if you look at the middle of the URL you see the stock ticker LMT.

```
import os
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import bs4 as bs
import pickle
import requests

def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})

    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)

    with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers, f)

    print(tickers)
    return tickers

#save_sp500_tickers()


def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):
    if reload_sp500:
        tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)

    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

    start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime(2016, 12, 31)

    for ticker in tickers:
        print(ticker)
        # just in case your connection breaks, we'd like to save our progress!
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
            df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        else:
            print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))

get_data_from_yahoo()
```